# _set_css_in_cell_output() error in IPython Notebooks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, google-earth-engine, python-3.10

I'm running a ipynb notebook in VS Code with the Jupyter extensions from Windows. I have the standalone Python installer (not Anaconda) version 3.10.11 and I created a virtual environment to work in.
For every cell I run I get:

```
 Error in callback <function _set_css_in_cell_output at 0x0000019337122170> (for pre_run_cell):
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: _set_css_in_cell_output() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

but the cell actually runs and gives me the output it is supposed to.
The code was developed by one of my colleagues who is running it in Jupyter notebook for Conda and she does not have this issue. It is using the packages from Google Earth Engine.

The problem is not major clearly since the code ultimately works, but is a bit annoying to get errors in every cell, so I would like to understand what the issue is.

Comment: are you using any of the additional tools that show up in this search query? https://github.com/search?q=%22_set_css_in_cell_output%22&type=code Ex. geemap?

Comment: Can you explain where the `_set_css_in_cell_output` function in the error code came from? Or you can provide [minimal reproducible example](
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to Reproduce the issue.

Comment: There is no _set_css_in_cell_output in the cell I have the error in, but I am using geemap. However I get the error in every cell after I imported the geemap package (but not in the actual cell where I import it) even though I'm not using any of the command of the package.

Comment: If I move the import of the package elsewhere I get the error in the cell after the one where I imported it, regardless the use of the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a case of this bug: [_set_css_in_cell_output error
#1811](https://github.com/gee-community/geemap/issues/1811), which got fixed by this Pull Request: [Fix set css cell output error #1819](https://github.com/gee-community/geemap/pull/1819), which is part of [the v0.29.5 release](https://github.com/gee-community/geemap/releases/tag/v0.29.5). Try updating to a version of geemap that is at or greater than that release.

Comment: Yeah, I just found it and updated it, and also tried with the version of Ipython they were suggesting before the fix, but I still get the error. I'll try some more and the I will report it in Github if I still get it, thanks!

Comment: After a bit of installing and uninstalling both Ipython and geemap it worked